# Cannot install Python GDAL on Mac OSC High Sierra

Tags: python, django, path, filepath, gdal

completely stuck on this one.

trying to run Django (django==1.11.9) in a Python 3.6.3 virtualenv with PostGIS. HighSierra 10.13.6.

Originally I installed gdal2 via homebrew. brew installs GDAL 2.4.0

when I run make:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal \
        C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal \
        pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | cut -f-2 -d'.')
Collecting GDAL==2.2
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Found existing installation: GDAL 2.4.0
    Uninstalling GDAL-2.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-2.4.0
Successfully installed GDAL-2.2.0
python manage.py migrate
...
File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libgdal.so, 6): image not found
```

I've tried a few different uninstalls, installs, and symlinks (and disabling csrutil).

assuming it might be a GDAL version issue, I downgraded from `brew install` of 2.4 to 2.3.2 via: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/

```
$ gdal-config --version
2.3.2

$ pip3 install gdal==2.3.2

    changing mode of build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/wheel/GDAL-2.3.2.data/scripts/gdal_auth.py to 755
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-rnubsult/gdal/setup.py", line 435, in <module>
      setup(**setup_kwargs)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 213, in run
      archive_basename = self.get_archive_basename()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 161, in get_archive_basename
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 155, in get_tag
      assert tag == supported_tags[0]
  AssertionError

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gdal
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal
Installing collected packages: gdal
  Found existing installation: GDAL 2.3.0
    Uninstalling GDAL-2.3.0:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-2.3.0
  Running setup.py install for gdal ... done
Successfully installed gdal-2.3.2
```

but still same err:

```
...
File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libgdal.so, 6): image not found
make: *** [update] Error 1

 $ sudo find / -name libgdal.so
```

will return multiple "operations not permitted" so it seems like a system permissions or security issue?

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: I have run into issues like this a couple times when trying to install gdal. Have you been installing gdal using python or python3. Your post says 3.6 but its looks like you are using python/pip instead of python3/pip3? In my experience when installing gdal with homebrew it would not install a required dependency or would install a mismatched version. You have to hunt down the missing/mismatched version in take care of the dependency yourself. Were you following the guide on geodjango? You may also wanna try using anaconda instead, it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Disregard the python3/pip3 i see you have tried that.

Comment: thanks @Taylor yeah this is in a bad place, unfortunately mostly my own doing. I've got: org.gdal.gdal22-framework-yosemite org.gdal.gdal21-framework-mtlion org.gdal.gdal23-framework-elcapitan and I think my best bet is to try and uninstall them and start fresh

Comment: Starting over is not a bad option. I would recommend trying it with conda since it comes with many of the needed dependencies.

Comment: one consideration though is I'm in a python 3.6 env and conda requires python 3.7. but may need conda as a last resort

Comment: tried `conda install gdal`, to reinstall gdal, still same err

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189413/discussion-between-taylor-and-chris-b).

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve this by directly linking to GDAL as a local environment variable for settings.py

ex:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py'
```